# TTR Package not working in R 3.4.4

Tags: r

i want to use TTR package in order to do MACD,RSI and other calculations, i wrongly updated all my packages and now xts and other libraries were built under R 3.4.4 but TTR is still under 3.4.3 and wont work.

is there a way i can either update TTR or just roll back the libraries to R 3.4.3?

As a note in case it helps, whenever i try to use the library it returns null if used like this

```
  trendMACD<-MACD(tenWeeks[,NamesperColumn[4]])
```

and if used with more parameters like this

```
trendMACD<-MACD(tenWeeks[,NamesperColumn[4]],maType = "EMA")
```

i get the error

> Error in MACD(tenWeeks[, NamesperColumn[4]], maType = "EMA") :
>   unused argument (maType = "EMA")

Comment: Yea, just update it. Many ways to do this. `pacman::p_load(TTR)` would be what I run, or do it with base R. If it gets stuck then just delete the library folder first.

Comment: thanks, but the problem is that TTR has not been compiled for R 3.4.4 i beileve :s

Comment: There should *never* be an issue between minor versions with the same x.y.* -- ie I have never seen this for, say, 3.4.3 and 3.4.4 -- apart from a harmless _warning_.  Now, between R 3.4.* and R 3.5.* you must indeed updated.  Which you should do anyway but that is a different topic.

Comment: that makes sense but at the same time i still cant use TTR, when i call the functions i.e MACD i get null returns when the same script did work before

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help anyone but the problem was R Studio IDE i had to do 2 things.

1) Restart my computer

2) Delete objects history from environment

Currently this is the version i'm using

Version 1.1.447